# Permission denied: calling a shell script from Python in a Jenkins job

Tags: python, bash, github, jenkins

Trying to provide the minimal amount of information necessary here, so I've left a lot out. Lots of similar questions around, but the most common answer (use `chmod +x`) isn't working for me.

I have a Python script and a shell script that sit next to each in a GitHub Enterprise repository:

[image]

Next, in Jenkins I check the code in this repository out. The two key steps in my Jenkinsfile are like so:

```
dir ("$WORK/python")
{           
    sh "chmod +x test.sh"
    sh "python3 foo.py -t '${AUTH}'"
}
```

Here, `$WORK` is the location on the Jenkins node that the code checks out to, and `python` (yes, poorly named) is the folder in the repository that the Python and shell script live in. Now, `foo.py` calls the shell script in this way:

```
try:
    cmd = f'test.sh {repo_name}'
    subprocess.Popen(cmd.split())

except Exception as e:
    print(f'Error during repository scan: {e}')
```

Here, `repo_name` is just an argument that I define above this snippet, that I'm asking the shell script to do something with. When I run the job in Jenkins, it technically executes without error, but the exception branch above does run:

```
11:37:24  Error during repository scan - [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test.sh'
```

I wanted to be sure that the `chmod` in the Jenkinsfile was running, so I opened a terminal to the machine that the code checked out to and found that the execute permissions were indeed correctly set:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 adm domain users   4106 Feb  6 14:24 foo.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 adm domain users    619 Feb  6 14:37 test.sh
```

I've gone around on this most of the day. What the heck is going on?

Comment: add `#!/usr/bin/python` in the first line of your source code, or if you use python 2.7 you can add `#!/usr/bin/python2.7`

Comment: I already use ````#!/usr/bin/python3```` at the top of my Python file, as well as ````#!/bin/bash```` at the top of my shell script, so I don't think it has to do with that.

Comment: Try using `/bin/bash test.sh` (or whatever interpreter is appropriate) in your subprocess. The only thing I can really think of that would allow the python script to run but not the bash script is if you have some kind of whitelisting utility on your system.

Comment: Also maybe check that the parent directories are executable for the user running this job and that the directory isn't on a mountpoint with noexec (check with `findmnt -T .`). The main difference between your two programs is that you're relying on the python script to be readable by `python3` but you're relying on the bash script to be an executable, so any external blockers to execution will permit the python script but not the bash script.

Comment: Interesting enough, if I execute ````test.sh```` manually in the node's terminal, after the Jenkins job has tried to run it, I get a successful execution. We do utilize shell scripts elsewhere in our codebase so I tend to think it's not a machine level issue like ````noexec````.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251674/discussion-between-tjm3772-and-pat-jones).

Comment: @tjm3772 - All the parent directory permissions look good. ````findmnt```` reveals some subdirectories under ````/sys```` which have ````noexec```` in place, but the directories important to the job are okay. If I do ````/bin/bash test.sh```` in the subprocess call the result in the console output is ````14:12:52  /bin/bash: test.sh: No such file or directory````.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this fixed it:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

cmd = f'{BASE_DIR}/test.sh {repo_name}'
Popen(cmd.split())
```

Why? In my ignorance associated with picking up someone else's code, I neglected to see, buried further up before the call to the shell script, that we change to a folder one level down:

```
os.chdir('repo_content')
```

The shell script does not, of course, live there. So calling it without specifying the path won't work. I'm not sure why this results in `[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test.sh'`, as that would imply that the shell script was found, but fully qualifying the path as above is doing exactly what I had hoped.